# How to dispose BitmapImage cache?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm facing a memory leak issue. The leak comes from here:

```
public static BitmapSource BitmapImageFromFile(string filepath)
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; //here
    bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache; //and here
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(filepath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    bi.EndInit();

    return bi;
}
```

I have a `ScatterViewItem`, which contains an `Image`, and the source is the `BitmapImage` of this function.

The actual thing is a lot more complex than this, so I can't simply put an Image into it. I also can't use the default load options, as the image file might be deleted and hence will face some permission issue accessing the file during deletion.

The problem occurs when I close the `ScatterViewItem`, which in turn closes the `Image`. However, the cached memory isnt cleared. So after many cycles, the memory consumption is pretty big.

I tried setting `image.Source=null` during the `Unloaded` function, but it didn't clear it.

How do I clear the memory correctly during unloading?

Comment: This might be of use to you [What is the correct way to free memory in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066200/what-is-the-correct-way-to-free-memory-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks, but the sad thing is the GC didn't collect it. Calling GC.Collect() directly didn't collect it either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202807/garbage-collection-fails-to-reclaim-bitmapimage). Seems like it's a bug in WPF.

I modified the function to include `Freeze`:

```
public static BitmapSource BitmapImageFromFile(string filepath)
{
    var bi = new BitmapImage();

    using (var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        bi.BeginInit();                
        bi.StreamSource = fs;                
        bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.EndInit();
    }

    bi.Freeze(); //Important to freeze it, otherwise it will still have minor leaks

    return bi;
}
```

I also create my own Close function, which will be called before I close the `ScatterViewItem`:

```
public void Close()
{
    myImage.Source = null;
    UpdateLayout();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Because `myImage` is hosted in a `ScatterViewItem`, `GC.Collect()` must be called before the parent is closed. Otherwise, it will still linger in memory.