# Can't delete a file after using it in a custom window (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, io

I have a custom window named ImageWindow, which has a `Image` control in it.

```
public void DownloadImageWithExtension(Uri url, ImageFormat format)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Delete(path));
    }
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(url, path);
    }
    ImageWindow iw = new ImageWindow(path);
    iw.ShowDialog();
}
```

This is my main windows code, which calls ImageWindow (iw) passing the file to open, which has been downloaded.

```
public partial class ImageWindow : Window
{
    public ImageWindow(string fileName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName));
        image_Image.Source = image; //Set Image controls image source to BitmapImage
    }
}
```

Here i get the image, save it to `BitmapImage` and add to `Source` of the `Image` control inside the newly opened window.

After i close the window and try to open the window again, i get this I/O exception.

> The process cannot access the file '\bin\Debug\10supercomfywallpapers!.Jpeg' because it is being used by another process.

I have found some fixes mentioning using dispose and such, but `BitmapImage` doesn't inherit `IDisposable`.

EDIT: The deletion will be moved to after the OpenDialog() returns, but i need to fix the window not disposing first to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dispose BitmapImage cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364439/how-to-dispose-bitmapimage-cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `CacheOption` to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`:

```
public partial class ImageWindow : Window
{
    public ImageWindow(string fileName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = new Uri(fileName);
        image.EndInit();
        image.Freeze();
        image_Image.Source = image; //Set Image controls image source to BitmapImage
    }
}
```

This should prevent the file from being locked.

Comment: What is stream supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. You should of course set the UriSource to a Uri.

Comment: It doesn't crash, but freezes.

Comment: Where does it freeze? ShowDialog() is blocking.

Comment: Freezes after downloading it, will try to get more details!

Comment: Does it freeze in the constructor of ImageWindow or after this one has returned?

Comment: Seems like it froze during the download. Went statement by statement. It did show the window a second time, but crashed during the download after third try of opening. EDIT: It definetly freezes during the download.

Comment: Well, then it has nothing to do with your original question about how to prevent the file from being locked. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Yeah, well didn't know it would go this way. Thanks!